# Linq: the query with Grouping, having and Max

Tags: linq, group-by, max

I'm trying to run the following MS SQL query:

```
 select PolicyCode, OccupancyCode, premiumcode, VersionNumber, rate
 from COVERAGE_RATES as cov
 group by PolicyCode, OccupancyCode, PremiumCode,VersionNumber, rate
 having (VersionNumber = 25 or VersionNumber = 
 (
     select MAX(versionnumber) from COVERAGE_RATES where
     PolicyCode = 4 and OccupancyCode=2 and PremiumCode = cov.PremiumCode
 ) ) and PolicyCode = 4
 AND OccupancyCode = 2
```

The idea is to take records where VersionNumber is 25 or, if there is no such version in the group, take the maximum number. That is if we have the table:

```
policyCode Version ...
----------------------
1          2
1          10
2          1
2          25
2          26
```

We should have the following result:

```
policyCode Version ...
----------------------
1          10
2          25
```

The Linq code is:

```
var res = (from c in CoverageRate
                       group c by c.PolicyCode
                           into rateGroup
                           where rateGroup.Any(r => r.VersionNumber == versionNumber ||
                           r.VersionNumber == 
                           CoverageRate.Where(c2 => c2.OccupancyCode == occupancyCode && c2.PolicyCode == policyCode)
                               .Max(c2 => c2.VersionNumber))
                           select rateGroup);
```

But I suppose I'm doing something wrong because when I try to take res.Count() I have the following error:

Unable to create a constant value of type '..CoverageRate'. Only primitive types ('such as Int32, String, and Guid') are supported in this context.

Could someone help me with this query?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Update - I think you are looking for this:

```
var res =  from c in CoverageRate
           group c by c.PolicyCode into rateGroup
           select rateGroup.OrderByDescending(x => x.VersionNumber)
                           .FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Let me check this one. Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately I have the same error. :( I know the problem is the part with max. As soon as I change it to some number it works. For some reason linq doesn't like working with max.

Comment: @Seacat - Are you using Linq to Entities or something similar?

Comment: Thanks for the update but I think it's wrong because I need to know not the whole max through the table but for every group. The records should be grouped by policyCode and I need to find if every group has record with Version equal 25 or, if not, take the maximum value that will be different for every group.

Comment: Yes, I use link to entities. Actually it's EF4.1 and I work inside the repository.

Comment: Hmmm... interesting. Now I don't have any errors, good. But now I don't know how to work with this data? It has inside 6 vars (groups I suppose), how can I extract the real CoverageRate data? Thanks

Comment: @Seacat - I think I finally understand what you are trying to do. I updated the answer, let me know if you encounter any other issues

Comment: Unfortunately it's not what I need. I would like to explain better. I need select all of the records, group by policy code and then select from every group only that record where versionNumber == 25 or max in this group. See updates in the question also.

Comment: Oh, I guess there is no sense to group by policy if I select by policy. Let me think a little bit more to find what I think wrong.

Answer (score 1):

```
from c in CoverageRate
                       group c by c.PolicyCode
                           into g
                           select new
                        {
                            policyCode = g.Key,
                            Version = (from t2 in g select t2.VersionNumber).Max()
                        }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but the result is the same. Actually the goal is not to know the count but just make it work. Because what I'm doing by call Count() is I just make the Linq execute the query and see if it works. But it doesn't :(